# Problems using JSON data in MVC controller and view

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, parsing, controller

I am a inexperienced programmer and have been trying to take data from a json object and display it in a chart using MVC and google charts but I have been getting this error "Unhandled exception at line 14, column 5 in localhost:53128/Coin/Index 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: '$' is undefined". Hopefully someone can try help me out a little.

JSON object called "MOCK_JSON.json":

```
    [{"id":1,"CoinValue":0.01,"Count":82,"CoinWeight":76},
    {"id":2,"CoinValue":0.02,"Count":86,"CoinWeight":18},
    {"id":3,"CoinValue":0.05,"Count":29,"CoinWeight":42},
    {"id":4,"CoinValue":0.1,"Count":35,"CoinWeight":90},
    {"id":5,"CoinValue":0.2,"Count":23,"CoinWeight":3},
    {"id":30,"CoinValue":0.5,"Count":41,"CoinWeight":36}]
```

Coin Class:

```
    public class Coin
{
    public int ID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string CoinValue
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int CoinWeight
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

}

Coin model:

```
    public class CoinModel
{
    public IList<Coin> coins;
}
```

Coin controller:

```
public class CoinController : Controller
    {
    // GET: Coin
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Data()
    {
        var fileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath(@"~/App_Data\MOCK_DATA.json"));
        var coins = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CoinModel>>(fileContents);

        //var coins = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CoinModel>(fileContents);

        return View(coins);
    }
}
```

View:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Coin Statistics Chart</title>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "Json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: '@Url.Action("Data", "Coin")',//GETS TO THIS LINE AND BREAKS
        success: function (result) {
            google.charts.load('current', {
                'packages': ['corechart']
            });
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function () {
                drawChart(result);
            });
        }
    });

    function drawChart(result) {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn("string", "CoinValue"); //might have to be changed
        data.addColumn("number", "Count");
        var dataArray = [];
        $.each(result, function (i, obj) {
            dataArray.push([obj.CoinValue, obj.Vounter]);
        });
        data.addRows(dataArray);

        var piechart_options = {
            title: 'Coin Tracker Piechart',
            width: 400,
            height: 300
        };

        var piechart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart_div'));
        piechart.draw(data, piechart_options);

        var barchart_options = {
            title: 'Coin Tracker barchart',
            width: 400,
            height: 300,
            legend: 'none'
        };

        var barchart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('barchart_div'));
        barchart.draw(data, barchart_options);
    }
});
</script>
```

HTML in view:

```
<body>
<table class="columns">
    <tr>
        <td><div id="piechart_div" style="border:1px solid #ccc"></div></td>
        <td><div id="barchart_div" style="border:1px solid #ccc"></div></td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You forgot to mention what your error is, but looking at the code, returning a View to the ajax call returns the whole View's HTML, just using the `coins` as the Model variable for that view. It doesn't return JSON. You should do `return Json(coins);` I think.

Comment: the error showing is "Unhandled exception at line 14, column 5 in http://localhost:53128/Coin/Index

0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: '$' is undefined"

Comment: no difference when i changed it to 'return Json(coins);'. Thanks for your input though!

Comment: "$ is undefined" suggests you haven't included jQuery in your page. I see you've put a `<script>` reference to it, so check that file exists and your webserver has permission to it. You can also check your browser's network tab at page load to see if it actually loads successfully into the page or not. So nothing to do with the server side change (although I still think you will need to do that as well)

Comment: Yes this was the problem, thank you very much!